# generating certain assets in production after changes are made - Nuxt.js

Tags: assets, nuxt.js

I store user uploaded images inside `/assets` directory, so I serve them using `require()` which takes an uploaded image built inside `_nuxt` directory.

Now these uploads can be uploaded by users through the form and in production after every upload made I need to build them manually through the command line since the assets are not built on changes as it is in development.

Is there a sollution to build certain assets (uploaded images) after changes are made in production?

Comment: Why just not to upload them somewhere and just reference them as static files?

Comment: @Aldarund in this case the images are not encoded and minimized and performannce of a web greatly falls (Lighthouse)

Comment: soo, you should do it on backend. Upload your image to backend, optimize it there and then return url to front

Comment: @Aldarund I tried! optimizing live before serving really makes the API so slow!